# Calculate PBKDF2 Sha256 in C# - Same results, different data

Tags: hash, sha256, pbkdf2

I've tried to calculate a hashed password.

The mechanism is decribed here:

**German:** https://avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Global/Service/Schnittstellen/AVM_Technical_Note_-_Session_ID_deutsch_2021-05-03.pdf

**English:** https://avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Global/Service/Schnittstellen/AVM_Technical_Note_-_Session_ID_english_2021-05-03.pdf

First step, to get the challenge from an HTTP-Request with follwing result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SessionInfo>
    <SID>0000000000000000</SID>
    <Challenge>2$60000$f56cbe583d35a155cfbdf24c8d6bfa45$6000$99a2a02c9bd6989e52307a6e83bab646</Challenge>
    <BlockTime>0</BlockTime>
    <Rights></Rights>
    <Users>
        <User last="1">root</User>
    </Users>
</SessionInfo>
```

The challenge is build as following data:

```
<type>$<ter1>$<salt1>$<ter2>$<salt2>

<iter1> = 60000
<salt1> = f56cbe583d35a155cfbdf24c8d6bfa45
<iter2> = 6000
<salt2> = 99a2a02c9bd6989e52307a6e83bab646
```

The password will hashed as following (source from code in PDF):

```
# Hash twice, once with static salt...
hash1 = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", password.encode(), salt1, iter1)

# Once with dynamic salt.
hash2 = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", hash1, salt2, iter2)
```

And here is my `C#` Code to try the hashing:

```
private void CreateChallenge(String challenge, LoginData data) {
    // PBKDF2 (ab FRITZ!OS 7.24)
    if(challenge.Contains("$")) {
        String[] parts  = challenge.Split('$');
        String type     = parts[0];                             // 2
        int iter1       = int.Parse(parts[1]);                  // 600000
        byte[] salt1    = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parts[2]);     // HEX
        int iter2       = int.Parse(parts[3]);                  // 600000
        byte[] salt2    = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parts[4]);     // HEX

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Salt 1:  " + parts[2] + " ~> " + iter1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Salt 2:  " + parts[4] + " ~> " + iter2);

        // Calculate
        byte[] hash1 = HMAC(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.Password), salt1, iter1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Hashed PW: " + BitConverter.ToString(hash1).Replace("-", ""));

        byte[] hash2 = HMAC(hash1, salt2, iter2);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Hashed Request: " + BitConverter.ToString(hash2).Replace("-", ""));

        this.CallSignin(parts[4] + "$" + BitConverter.ToString(hash2).Replace("-", "").ToLower(), data);
        // MD5-Fallback
    } else {
        this.CallSignin(challenge + "-" + MD5(challenge + "-" + data.Password), data);
    }
}

private byte[] HMAC(byte[] input, byte[] salt, int iterations) {

    using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(input, salt, iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)) {

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pbkdf2.ToString());
        //return pbkdf2.GetBytes(length);
    }
}

private String MD5(String input) {
    MD5 hasher              = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] data             = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    StringBuilder output    = new StringBuilder();

    for(int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++) {
        output.Append(data[index].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return output.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

And here is a sample Call:

```
CreateChallenge("2$60000$f56cbe583d35a155cfbdf24c8d6bfa45$6000$99a2a02c9bd6989e52307a6e83bab646", new LoginData() {
    Username = "root",
    Password = "123Test"
});
```

But **curiously** i've get follwing output:

```
Salt 1:  f56cbe583d35a155cfbdf24c8d6bfa45 ~> 60000
Salt 2:  99a2a02c9bd6989e52307a6e83bab646 ~> 6000
Hashed PW: 53797374656D2E53656375726974792E43727970746F6772617068792E526663323839384465726976654279746573
Hashed Request: 53797374656D2E53656375726974792E43727970746F6772617068792E526663323839384465726976654279746573
Result: 99a2a02c9bd6989e52307a6e83bab646$53797374656d2e53656375726974792e43727970746f6772617068792e526663323839384465726976654279746573
```

**Question**

WHY is the `Hashed PW` complete the same as `Hashed Request`?

Both using other values..

Can anyone help me?

Change the `HMAC` Method and tried to use other mechanics for `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WHY is the Hashed PW complete the same as Hashed Request?

Your `HMAC()` method, which is supposed to perform a key derivation with PBKDF2, returns `pbkdf2.ToString()`, which always is *System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes* regardless of the input data.
Correct would be to return `pbkdf2.GetBytes(32)` instead (this line is present in your code, but commented out for some reason).
Note that PBKDF2 uses an HMAC internally, but is not identical to it, so the name of the method is misleading and it should be renamed.

Fix of the method `HMAC()`:

```
private static byte[] HMAC(byte[] input, byte[] salt, int iterations)
{
    using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(input, salt, iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
    {
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(32); // apply GetBytes()
    }
}
```

---

A second problem is that the salt is hex encoded, so it must be hex decoded with `Convert.FromHexString()` (and not UTF-8 encoded with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`).

Fix in `CreateChallenge()`:

```cs
...
byte[] salt1 = Convert.FromHexString(parts[2]); // hex decode...
...
byte[] salt2 = Convert.FromHexString(parts[4]); // hex decode...
...
```

---

The linked documentation describes a test case ([here](https://avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Global/Service/Schnittstellen/AVM_Technical_Note_-_Session_ID_english_2021-05-03.pdf), sec. *Calculating the Response Value*):

> The example challenge “2$10000$5A1711$2000$5A1722” and the password
> “1example!“ (utf8-encoded) results in:
>
> hash1 =
> pbdkf2_hmac_sha256(“1example!”, 5A1711, 10000)
> => 0x23428e9dec39d95ac7a40514062df0f9e94f996e17c398c79898d0403b332d3b (hex)
>
> response = 5A1722$ + pbdkf2_hmac_sha256(hash1, 5A1722,
> 2000).hex()
> => 5A1722$1798a1672bca7c6463d6b245f82b53703b0f50813401b03e4045a5861e689adb

When the fixed code for this test case is executed:

```cs
CreateChallenge("2$10000$5A1711$2000$5A1722", new LoginData()
{
    Username = "root",
    Password = "1example!"
});
```

the expected results are returned:

```
Hashed PW: 23428E9DEC39D95AC7A40514062DF0F9E94F996E17C398C79898D0403B332D3B
Hashed Request: 1798A1672BCA7C6463D6B245F82B53703B0F50813401B03E4045A5861E689ADB
```

---

Note: In .NET 5 `Rfc2898DeriveBytes()` requires a salt which is at least 8 bytes long, in higher versions of .NET this constraint does not exist. Since in the test case only a 3 bytes salt is applied `Rfc2898DeriveBytes()` cannot be used with .NET 5. Instead C#/BouncyCastle can be applied:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
...
private static byte[] HMAC(byte[] input, byte[] salt, int iterations)
{
    var pbkdf2 = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest());
    pbkdf2.Init(input, salt, iterations);
    var pbkdf2KeyParam = (KeyParameter)pbkdf2.GenerateDerivedMacParameters(32 * 8);
    return pbkdf2KeyParam.GetKey();
}
```

Comment: Have a big thanks! Yes, i've seen already, that `ToString` the Class-name returned. It was only a testing case before i've post here. And thanks for the tinfo because the hex-salts!